# Create a 3D push button in android

Tags: android-layout

I want to make [this button](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_3d_push_button/#) (or something similar) in android.
I don't now how to make that with only [those](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape) attributes.

Or there is other approach how to make button down effect?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a lot of research and some work, made this:

https://github.com/inlacou/Button3D

I hope it helps.